# Cycles renderer crashes at random moments

Tags: cycles-render-engine, error

I have a problem with cycles engine. While rendering any scene (no matter how complicated it is) my Blender just crashes at random moments with black screen for a few seconds. I've searched so many forums and threads and now I feel like I am the only one who have this trouble. I've tried basically everything, from reinstalling blender to updating all drivers on my PC, but nothing works. So, I need to know how to solve this and what could be the problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to render on a different computer? Have you tried to render with CPU? I suspect that it is a hardware problem.

Comment: Yep, Im rendering with CPU. On another computers there is no such problem.